# Sending argument to another method

Tags: java, variables, methods, arguments

I would like to send the **file** variable from the **bookListView LongClickListener** to the switch statements from the **QuickAction code**. How would I do this?

BookListView code:

```
bookListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(
    new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String book = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            File file = new File (path + "/" + book);
            mQuickAction.show(view);
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```

QuickAction code:

```
ActionItem editItem = new ActionItem(ID_EDIT, "Edit", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_icon));
ActionItem deleteItem = new ActionItem(ID_DELETE, "Delete", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.delete_icon));

final QuickAction mQuickAction  = new QuickAction(this);
mQuickAction.addActionItem(editItem);
mQuickAction.addActionItem(deleteItem);

mQuickAction.setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(QuickAction quickAction, int pos, int actionId) {
        ActionItem actionItem = quickAction.getActionItem(pos);

        switch (actionId) {
            case ID_EDIT:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "go", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case ID_DELETE:
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Delete book", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 break;
            }
        }
    });

    mQuickAction.setOnDismissListener(new QuickAction.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            //close quickaction
        }
    });

   ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a object, which is responsible for managing the file, like:

```
public class FileManager {

    private File file;

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return this.file;
    }
}
```

The `FileManager` could be shared between the methods:

```
FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();

bookListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String book = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
        File file = new File (path + "/" + book);
        fileManager.setFile(file);
        mQuickAction.show(view);
        return true;
    }
});
```

and than you could call the get method:

```
mQuickAction.setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(QuickAction quickAction, int pos, int actionId) {
        ActionItem actionItem = quickAction.getActionItem(pos);
        File file = fileManager.getFile();

        switch (actionId) {
            case ID_EDIT:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "go", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case ID_DELETE:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Delete book", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    ...
});
```